Inverse Radon transform for specific pairs of sinograms
Let $f_1, f_2$ be two functions defined on the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2, f_i \in L^2(\mathbb{B}^2, \mathbb{R})$
For which tuples $(f_1, f_2)$ does it hold
$\mathcal{R}[f_1](y, \alpha) = \mathcal{R}[f_2](y, \alpha) \tan \alpha$
where $\mathcal{R}$ denotes the Radon transform.
As a trivial example, $(0,0)$ is such a tuple. Since these tuples form a vector space, a basis would be sufficient.

Integrating above equation along $y$ and noting that the result for the sinograms does not depend on $\alpha$ yields $\int f_i dxdy=0$ as necessary condition (this is sufficient in my case)
